# replay "script" of keystrokes in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I would like to record a medium-length screencast of some Emacs functionality using [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/) in a terminal. I could just start `asciinema`, then `emacs -nw`, do the recording, then stop. But I find that I always make multiple mistakes.

So I thought that it would be great if I could just write a "script" of keystrokes in some format, that would be fed to Emacs. Like replaying a keyboard macro, but a fairly long one, and with delays between keys (otherwise the recording goes way too fast).

Is this possible somehow? I am willing to do some elisp programming, but don't know where to start. Eg I could record my script as a list,

```
(list (kbd "C-x C-f") "filename.el" (kbd "C-e") (kbd "C-x C-e") ...)
```

and iterate through it, converting keystrokes and sending strings by character verbatim, but how do I "send" the result to Emacs?

It would be great if buffer switching etc would work.

Comment: Nice idea, did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can record a sequence of user actions (keyboard, menus, etc.), creating a **keyboard macro**.

In a nutshell, you use `<f3>` to start recording and `<f4>` to stop recording.  Then you can use `<f4>` (same key) to play back the recording.  You can do all kinds of fancy things, in addition, but those are the basics.

See the Emacs manual, node [Keyboard Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) for details.

---

You can show which keys are being used during your screencast in a tooltip, using mode **`showkey-tooltip-mode`** from library [`showkey.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/showkey.el) - see [ShowKey](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowKey).

To show the keys recorded by the macro you will need to set or bind option `showkey-tooltip-sleep-time` to a number of seconds greater than zero.  (By default it is zero, so that you can prevent some key display by typing quickly.)

Option `showkey-tooltip-key-only-flag` controls whether to show only the key, or the key and its command, in the tooltip.

Alternatively, you can show an incremental log of the keys using mode **`showkey-log-mode`**.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of keyboard macros (I mentioned them in the question), but AFAIK the format is opaque. Ideally, I would prefer to record small sequences, paste them together into something big, and edit as necessary.